# JavaFX rectangle rotation pivot from point other than top left

Tags: java, javafx

I have applied a JavaFx `Rotation` to a rectangle using the constructor that allows you to set the pivot

```
new Rotate(45, 15, 15)
```

This rotates the rectangle but it rotates around the top left corner at `15,15` on the `AnchorPane` in which it is placed. Is it possible to rotate a rectangle around a point that acts like the center of a circle and the rectangle rotates around the circumfrence. Like the rectangle is a piece of tread on a tire that rotates around the central pivot. Thanks heaps.

Comment: A piece of tread on a tire rotating is just what you say, set the pivot to be the center of the tire. If that doesn't work, maybe explain what is wrong. Or make a small application to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: If I do this the rectangle's top left corner goes straight to the center of the "tire". Is there anyway to increase the distance from the pivot like swinging around a ball on a 1 meter rope. (So it has a circular motion not just rotating the top left corner around the pivot).

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code? How are you applying your transform.

Comment: Just place the pivot point outside of the `Rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks guys works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, I am not sure what you are doing though.

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.Duration;

/**
 * Created by Matt on 25/08/16.
 */
public class RotatingARectangle extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        Group root = new Group();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(190, 395, 20, 5);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        Rotate rot = new Rotate(0, 200, 200);
        rect.getTransforms().add(rot);

        Ellipse path = new Ellipse(200, 200, 200, 200);
        path.setStroke(Color.RED);
        path.setFill(null);

        root.getChildren().add(rect);
        root.getChildren().add(path);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Timeline line = new Timeline(30);

        KeyFrame key1 = new KeyFrame(
                new javafx.util.Duration(0),
                new KeyValue(rot.angleProperty(), 0 )
        );

        KeyFrame key2 = new KeyFrame(
            new javafx.util.Duration(1000),
            new KeyValue(rot.angleProperty(), 360 )
        );
        line.getKeyFrames().addAll(key1, key2);

        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt->{
            line.playFromStart();
        });



    }

}
```

I set the pivot to be the center of the elipse, then use a timeline to change the angle from 0 to 360.

Comment: Yeah it was my bad originally, thanks for the detailed answer.